# can we give capital letter and underscore in pdo named placeholder

Tags: php, oop, pdo, placeholder

Can we give capital letter and underscore in PDO named place holder.
Below Is my query:

> insert into product_pepe (Type_Class,
>   ID_Alias, Sort_order_Position,
>   DaysBeforeReminder,
>   DaysForNxtVaccination,
>   IsSitemapple_IsSitemappable,
>   NoFollowUpVaccinations,
>   NoOfReminders_NoOfReminders,
>   NoVaccinationsInPacket, RRP_RRP,
>   RemindersInterval, SendReminderEmail,
>   SendReminderSMS, SpecialInstructions,
>   Visible, List_price_AUD_gross,
>   Daily_price_dependent, Taxclass,
>   Order_unit, Quantity_for_price,
>   Minimum_order_quantity, IntervalOrder,
>   Reference_unit, Reference_am,
>   Amount_in_product, Manufacturer,
>   Manufacturer_product_no, Weight_unit,
>   Weight, Length, Height, Width,
>   Stock_level, Minimum_stock_level,
>   DeliveryPeriod, Name_en,
>   Description_en, LongDescription_en,
>   Keywords_en, IsNew, IsAvailable,
>   AvailabilityDate,
>   AvailabilityComment_en,
>   IsBundleProduct, SuperProduct,
>   SelectedVariations, IsDefault,
>   HasSubOwnPrices, ImageSmall,
>   ImageMedium, ImageLarge, ImageHotDeal,
>   ImagesSlideShowString, Size,
>   Metalicussize, XXS_XL, EuroSize,
>   AusShoeSize, CLSShoeSize_CLS,
>   SIZES_SizesXS_XL, SIZES_TTJSize,
>   CristinaRe_Envelopesize,
>   CristinaRe_Paperweight,
>   CristinaRe_packorpersheet,
>   Cristina_Re_DIYsize,
>   Metalicus_Metalicus, EeniMeeniMini
>   Moh_Color, FishLillyBibs_Sizes,
>   Basic_Colours, Basic_Shoesize,
>   Basic_Sizeother2, Basic_toshihatsize,
>   Basic_Sizebymonth,
>   Paperartzi_OobiSize,
>   Paperartzi_Paperartzi,
>   Colors_SolidColors,
>   Colors_StripeColors,
>   ToshiHats_hatsizes, Oobi_StripeColour,
>   Oobi_OtherColour, Oobi_BlockColour,
>   Oobi_OobiSize, Oobi_DressColour,
>   Oobi_MuslinDesigns, Oobi_Designs,
>   DieselShoeSize_ShoeSize,
>   WillowFinn_Sizes,
>   WalnutShoeSize_Shoesize,
>   Bugaboo_BugabooColorBase,
>   Bugaboo_BugabooColorTop,
>   MiniminkSize_MiniminkSize,
>   BuntingPattern_Pattern,
>   Bedding_Bedding) values (:Type_Class,
>   :ID_Alias, :Sort_order_Position,
>   :DaysBeforeReminder,
>   :DaysForNxtVaccination,
>   :IsSitemapple_IsSitemappable,
>   :NoFollowUpVaccinations,
>   :NoOfReminders_NoOfReminders,
>   :NoVaccinationsInPacket, :RRP_RRP,
>   :RemindersInterval,
>   :SendReminderEmail, :SendReminderSMS,
>   :SpecialInstructions, :Visible,
>   :List_price_AUD_gross,
>   :Daily_price_dependent, :Taxclass,
>   :Order_unit, :Quantity_for_price,
>   :Minimum_order_quantity,
>   :IntervalOrder, :Reference_unit,
>   :Reference_am, :Amount_in_product,
>   :Manufacturer,
>   :Manufacturer_product_no,
>   :Weight_unit, :Weight, :Length,
>   :Height, :Width, :Stock_level,
>   :Minimum_stock_level, :DeliveryPeriod,
>   :Name_en, :Description_en,
>   :LongDescription_en, :Keywords_en,
>   :IsNew, :IsAvailable,
>   :AvailabilityDate,
>   :AvailabilityComment_en,
>   :IsBundleProduct, :SuperProduct,
>   :SelectedVariations, :IsDefault,
>   :HasSubOwnPrices, :ImageSmall,
>   :ImageMedium, :ImageLarge,
>   :ImageHotDeal, :ImagesSlideShowString,
>   :Size, :Metalicussize, :XXS_XL,
>   :EuroSize, :AusShoeSize,
>   :CLSShoeSize_CLS, :SIZES_SizesXS_XL,
>   :SIZES_TTJSize,
>   :CristinaRe_Envelopesize,
>   :CristinaRe_Paperweight,
>   :CristinaRe_packorpersheet,
>   :Cristina_Re_DIYsize,
>   :Metalicus_Metalicus, :EeniMeeniMini
>   Moh_Color, :FishLillyBibs_Sizes,
>   :Basic_Colours, :Basic_Shoesize,
>   :Basic_Sizeother2,
>   :Basic_toshihatsize,
>   :Basic_Sizebymonth,
>   :Paperartzi_OobiSize,
>   :Paperartzi_Paperartzi,
>   :Colors_SolidColors,
>   :Colors_StripeColors,
>   :ToshiHats_hatsizes,
>   :Oobi_StripeColour, :Oobi_OtherColour,
>   :Oobi_BlockColour, :Oobi_OobiSize,
>   :Oobi_DressColour,
>   :Oobi_MuslinDesigns, :Oobi_Designs,
>   :DieselShoeSize_ShoeSize,
>   :WillowFinn_Sizes,
>   :WalnutShoeSize_Shoesize,
>   :Bugaboo_BugabooColorBase,
>   :Bugaboo_BugabooColorTop,
>   :MiniminkSize_MiniminkSize,
>   :BuntingPattern_Pattern,
>   :Bedding_Bedding)

and its giving below error:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute() [pdostatement.execute]: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in D:\Users\avinash\liveprojects\peperatzi\importData\import.php on line 56
```

what can be the reason for this?

Comment: Holy.. Have you heard of normalization?

Comment: The problem is neither capital letters nor underscores, is it? `Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined`

Comment: yes i know, but I have to import this data into one table from csv so...

Comment: if you're importing from CSV, you might like to know about MySQL's `LOAD DATA INFILE` syntax (assuming your DB is mySQL, of course). It's a lot less hassle than writing a PHP loop to read from the file and insert into the DB, plus it's quicker to execute too.

Answer (score 1):

If you load that statement into a syntax-aware editor, you'll immediately see that there's a problem here:

```
:EeniMeeniMini Moh_Color,
```

You probably meant

```
:EeniMeeniMini_Moh_Color,
```

(Emacs highlighted it for me in the scratch buffer, so syntax-awareness isn't strictly necessary.)